# lacheck doesn't like factorials?

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, lacheck

I have the following code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$n!$
\end{document}
```

Running `lacheck` on it results

```
"test.tex", line 3: punctuation mark "!" should be placed after end of math mode
```

But this is factorial, so it makes sense to put it inside the math mode.

So, is it a bug of `lacheck`? Do you use this tool at all?

Comment: Use `$ n! $`  ;-) It's described in the manual that `lacheck` gets confused by punctuation marks right at  math mode delimiters. The white space in `$ n! $` does not hurt anyway

Comment: It's not the only thing that hurts `lacheck`. Just ignore.

Answer (score 3):

You could to use the `cool` package to have the correct symbol of factorial.
See this example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cool}
\begin{document}
$\Factorial{n}$
\end{document}
```